# HTML & CSS navigation bar simple question

Tags: css, wordpress

I cant for the life of me figure out how to edit the style.css file to edit the width of the top navigation bar. [our website](https://www.paincarecenters.com) as you can see, the top nav bar is too large, all the items should fit on one line. Here is the code:

```css
.top-nav {
     background: #151515 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
 .nav-top li {
    display: inline-block;
}
 .top-nav a,.nav-video a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: josefin_sansbold,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position:relative;
    font-size:30px;
}
 .top-nav{
    text-align: center;
}
 div#Video_Categories {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background: #fafafa;
}
 #nav a {
    color:#004282 !important;
    font-size:18px !important;
}
```

There is also a chance that I may be looking at the relavent code for the top menu bar. I could attach the full css file here if possible. Bare with me this is my first post!

Comment: Are you using any themes on your WordPress site? Check Theme's CSS file as well.

Comment: Yes, im in the Appearances>theme file editor and im in the style.css and I can edit it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ability to override your current styles or edit them, then you can change the width of the class `.container_24`.

```
.container_24 {
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Changing that gives me this:

[image]

Comment: How did you know to use that class? Are you looking at the style.css? or another file?

Comment: I inspected the console and looked at which class is controlling the width off that element. The width was originally 1170px and I just moved it out to an even 1200px and that did it.

Comment: As you stated in your comment above, you're in `Appearances > Theme File Editor`... Make sure you're not modifying any core CSS files. In `Appearances`, there should be an `Additional CSS` option, [similar to this](https://davidsutoyo.com/wp-content/uploads/customizer-panel.png)... You would update your styles in there. It should open up to a window [that looks similar to this](https://davidsutoyo.com/wp-content/uploads/customizer-css-editor.png), where you can override anything.

Comment: You also don't need every property I mentioned in my original answer. You only need to override what you're changing. I've updated my original response.

Comment: I dont see additional CSS option in appearances. I'm so new here I dont even know how to attach a screenshot image. But basically when I click appearances all is see is: themes customize widgets menus header background and theme file editor. where is additional CSS?

Comment: To add an image here, you'll have to upload the image to imgur or another service. Then, do this... [image URL](image url)

Comment: [https://imgur.com/a/viA2eE5](https://imgur.com/a/viA2eE5)

Comment: Go to Customize. What's there?

Comment: I got it! However, the weirdest thing now, so within chrome browser, I have three different profiles logged in. On two of them the website looks fixed, however on the other profile it looks like the same two lines and the font is HUGE. Also, when I logged in on brave browser same problem! How could within chrome browser itself render two different pages? just because I'm logged into different google accounts. I cleared cache too.

Comment: It's possible you're caching. In Chrome, do this...  `⋮ > Settings > Privacy and Security > Clear browsing data > (under Basic) > Time Range: All time, Check: Cookies and other site data, Check: Cached images and files` and click `Clear Data`. That should clear your cache. Additionally, you can do what's called a **Hard Refresh** by pressing `ctrl + shift + r`. Let me know if that changes anything.